# platform-browser.umd.js:937 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load '*'

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I'm trying `angular2`, but I got stuck in an error `platform-browser.umd.js:937 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'ArticlesListComponent`

When I searched, I saw many answers to add `directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]`. But even after that I'm getting the same error. These are my files

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/views/main.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

app.articles.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'articles-list',
  templateUrl: 'app/views/articlelist.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class ArticlesListComponent {

}
```

app.routing.ts

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ArticlesListComponent } from './app.articles';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'articles',
    component: ArticlesListComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Articles List'
    }
  }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [

];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if you defined the base href in your index.html. if not add this add the beginning of your head tag.

```
<base href="/">
```

Assuming you are using the latest Angular 2 (RC5) then you don't need to include neither `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` nor import Router to your components if you define your app.module accordingly. A module is basically a way to help you bootstrap your app and organize declarations, providers in a systematic way. Here I show an example for a module:

```
import { NgModule }      from
'@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from. 
'@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }  from './ app.component';
//import routing path
//import ArticlesListComponent

@NgModule({
imports: [ BrowserModule, RouterModule] //,routing],
declarations: [ AppComponent,  ArticlesListComponent,
bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Try to read angular2: guide on modules. Also I would recommend you to follow the good practices on directory structure and file naming. You might find this useful aswell [Angular RC5 Modules](http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/08/angular-2-rc5-ngmodules-lazy-loading.html?m=1).